# Does replacing implicit conversion with explicit casting have any side-effects?

Tags: c, casting, implicit-conversion

Is it better to explicitly cast, rather than just use implicit conversion?

For example, I have an enum...

```
/*This enum represents the various encryption types for wifi. For wifi capable devices, a bitwise & result of all supported encryption types should be returned.*/
typedef enum wifi_encryptionType {
    /*Unknown encryption - default value, and for if wifi standard is ever expanded.*/
    WIFIENCTYPE_UNKNOWN = 0,

    /*No encryption - an open network.*/
    WIFIENCTYPE_NONE = 1,

    /*WEP encryption - all widths.*/
    WIFIENCTYPE_WEP = 2,

    /*WPA 1 with a preshared key using Temporal Key Integrity Protocol.*/
    WIFIENCTYPE_WPA_PSK_TKIP = 4,

    /*WPA 1 with a preshared key using Advanced Encryption Standard via CCMP. */
    WIFIENCTYPE_WPA_PSK_AES = 8,

    /*WPA 2 with a preshared key using Temporal Key Integrity Protocol.*/
    WIFIENCTYPE_WPA2_PSK_TKIP = 16,

    /*WPA 2 with a preshared key using Advanced Encryption Standard via CCMP.*/
    WIFIENCTYPE_WPA2_PSK_AES = 32

} wifi_encryptionType;
```

Which I use in a struct.

```
typedef struct {
    char ssid[32];
    wifi_encryptionType encryption;
    wifi_mode mode;
} WifiNetwork;
```

and I use the value of that struct's field as a parameter for a function call...

```
read_uint8(readBuffer, &network.encryption);
//read_uint8 takes a struct pointer containing some buffer info, and a uint8_t pointer.
```

I get a warning.

```
warning: passing argument 2 of 'read_uint8' from incompatible pointer type
expected 'uint8_t *' but argument is of type 'enum wifi_encryptionType *'
```

I get what the warning means. "Be aware that reading a `uint8_t` and putting it into a `wifi_encryptionType` field can place values in there that do not map to any of the values you have declared."

The type conversion is done implicitly right now.

Is it better to make it an explicit cast? Are there any benefits to making the cast explicit - or any downsides?

Comment: As the tag point to, there is no "*implicit casting*", but only "*implicit conversion*", Casting is "*explicit*" by definition.

Comment: @alk Yeah, it's a definition mismatch on my part. I see the code as "doing" things (it converts the value) rather than letting it happen (the value gets converted somehow). My bad. I fixed the question body, and updated the question title to be more specific to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning in this case isn't just the compiler nitpicking. That might potentially break.

The reason is that the `enum` type might have a different size than `uint8_t`. The C11 standard only guarantees that (section 6.7.2.2)

> Each enumerated type shall be compatible with `char`, a signed integer type, 
>   or an unsigned integer type.

If you get unlucky and the `enum` has the same representation as e.g. `int`, then you'd be effectively passing a pointer to the initial byte of an `int`. On a big-endian system, that byte would not have the same value as the `int`, even if the value would fit.

Another issue (which probably wouldn't apply here though) is *strict aliasing*, which means that the compiler is allowed to assume that the same data isn't accessed as two different types. An example would be having an `int*` and a `float*` point to the same location, writing to that location via the `int*`, and then reading from it via the `float*`. Strict aliasing rules allow for code optimization, as the compiler can assume that writing via the `int*` won't mess up the value the `float*` points to (so that it would have to be reloaded into a register for example).

The reason strict aliasing probably wouldn't apply here is that `uint8_t` in practice is almost certain to be `unsigned char`, for which the compiler makes an exception. A `char*` (or `unsigned char*`) can be used to access the memory of any type of object. If this wasn't allowed, then there wouldn't be any safe way to do "raw" byte operations as needed by e.g. `memcpy()`.

Comment: Ooh, endianness. ... Yeah, that could screw some things up. ... it'd be really weird too, working on some devices and not working on others.

Comment: @Pimgd: I've seen a few bugs like this in the wild, where people passed a pointer to some type, converted it to a pointer to a different, accidentally larger type, and then assigned to that type via the pointer, leading to memory corruption. Here that particular case wouldn't be a problem, but it's worth looking out for too. The best solution is to explicitly create an object of the right type and pass the pointer to that. (As a side note, converting pointers might also break strict aliasing rules, though it's probably safe here since `uint8_t` is likely to be `char`.)

Comment: Strict aliasing means that the compiler is allowed to assume that two pointers of different type do not alias (point to the same place) under certain circumstances by the way. (You're not allowed to "access" the same data as two different types is another way to put it.) It allows for more efficient code generation in some cases. There's an exception for `char*`/`unsigned char*` pointers though -- those are allowed to alias other pointers. (Otherwise it would be tricky to do "raw" byte operations as needed by e.g. `memcpy()`.)

Comment: Added it to the answer too. :P

Comment: So any pointer conversions like these are basically bad news, and I should fix them, rather than hiding them behind explicit casts.

Comment: @Pimgd: It's safer to create a separate object of the right type and pass a pointer to that at least (and cleaner too, usually). Strict aliasing is one of those vague "often works in practice" things though. Some projects that do a lot of memory trickery (e.g., the Linux kernel) turn off strict aliasing (by passing `-fno-strict-aliasing` to GCC) to make things safer that way. That probably isn't warranted for most code though.

Comment: Many thanks for your help - I'll fix my warnings by using a separate object, rather than ignoring or filtering the warnings by defines or pointer conversions.

Comment: One thing that's strictly a strict aliasing violation that I've seen many times in practice is having a `union` and writing a value to one member and reading it from another. My guess is that it's such a common idiom point that compilers make sure that it works.

Comment: @Pimgd: In recent versions of the C language, you can declare an enum together with the underlying type. For example typedef enum wifi_encryptionType : uint8_t { ... }. An enum value will be stored in exactly the same way as a uint8_t.

Comment: @gnasher729 I'm pretty much bound to C89/C90. Thanks for the info, though.

Comment: @gnasher729: Sure you're not thinking of C++? Can't find that in C11.

Answer (score 0):

An `enum` (most likley) is an `int`.

So you are passing the address of an `int` where the address of a `uint8_t` is expected.

The compiler tells you this:

```
warning: passing argument 2 of 'read_uint8' from incompatible pointer type expected 'uint8_t *' but argument is of type 'enum wifi_encryptionType *'
```

Doing so is a recipe for disaster.

To get around this use an temporary intermediate variable:

```
{
  uint8_t tmp = network.encryption;
  read_uint8(readBuffer, &tmp);
  network.encryption = tmp;
}
```

Comment: Why is it a recipe for disaster? Can you give an example of something that might go wrong?

Comment: The sizes of the `enum` and the `uint8_t` could very well be different, and then access the variable's memory via dereferencing a pointer inside the called function would fail. @Pimgd

Comment: When you pass the address of a four byte int cast as a uint8_t*, assigning to the uint8_t* will only change one byte of the int and leave three bytes unchanged, probably rubbish. Because of byte ordering you don't know which byte is changed. Passing the address of a uint8_t and casting it to int* is worse; assigning to the int* will change the original uint8_t and three more bytes in memory.